# When to use fabsf rather than fabs

Tags: c++

I was wondering in what scenario would I use `fabs` over `fabsf` (from cmath/math.h)?

Or explain the difference seeing as it looks like one just calls the other.

The definitions I have in my math.h are

```
_Check_return_ inline float fabs(_In_ float _Xx) _NOEXCEPT

_Check_return_ __inline float __CRTDECL fabsf(_In_ float _X)
```

Comment: The first takes a double the other a float.  Pick the one that uses the type you are using.

Comment: I thought they both took a float?

Comment: also, please if people want to vote a question down at least have the decency to write a comment on how to improve it.

Comment: You should check the [reference material](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs)

Comment: @unknownSPY I'm going to guess the downvotes are because this question very likely could have been answered if you looked up the documention for each.

Comment: @NathanOliver my copy of math.h has this as the signiture `_Check_return_ __inline float __CRTDECL fabsf(_In_ float _X)` rather than double

Comment: @unknownSPY What what does it have for `fabs`?

Comment: @NathanOliver `_Check_return_ inline float fabs(_In_ float _Xx) _NOEXCEPT`

Comment: C89 7.12.7.2 defines `fabs` as `double fabs(double x);`.  Your implementation looks broken/non-compliant.

Comment: @NathanOliver not necessarily, if the file is reused for C++, and the declaration is protected by `__cplusplus` macro conditional.

Comment: @user2079303 Oh wow.  I just rechecked the C++14 standard and it actually has `float fabs(float)` and it uses `abs` as the standard C `fabs`.  Crazy

Comment: So maybe all those down votes should be nullified...

Comment: @unknownSPY [Some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23474796/968363) asks about a fast fabsf implementation which might be circuitously relevant. As this is math-lib territory I'd suspect any differences below the headers will depend on your link and architecture options.

Answer (score 4):

> When to use `fabsf` rather than `fabs`

In C++, there is hardly ever a reason to use `fabsf`. Use `std::abs` instead with floating point types. `std::fabs` may have use when you wish to convert the absolute value of an integer to `double`, but that's probably quite niche use case.

If you were writing C instead, then it is almost as simple: Use `fabsf` when you have a `float`, and `fabs` when you have a `double`. Same applies to other standard math functions with `f` suffix.

> The definitions I have in my math.h are
>
> ```
> _Check_return_ inline float fabs(_In_ float _Xx) _NOEXCEPT
> ```

The C++ standard library specifies overloads for `std::fabs`. One of them takes a `float`. Your standard library is not standard compliant, if the other overloads are missing.

The C standard library specifies `double fabs(double)`. Your standard library is not standard compliant, if the quoted declaration applies to C.